# Como saber em que linguagem um programa foi escrito?

Tags: windows, .exe, engenharia-reversa

Baixei um programa no *Windows*, e nele não consigo obter informações sobre em qual linguagem foi programado. Há como saber?

Answer (score 21):

De forma geral, fácil e garantida não tem como saber.

Pode olhar o binário em um editor que permita isso (provavelmente um [editor hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors)) e procurar por assinaturas do binário que entregue a informação. É comum o compilador colocar algo que indique o que foi usado para gerar aquele binário.

Se não der, pode procurar por funções comuns usadas na biblioteca da linguagem. Mas isso pode dar falsos positivos, especialmente se for funções de C. Teria que usar outros critérios para confirmar.

Tem binários fora do padrão, isso pode ajudar ou dificultar a identificação. Obviamente que até o momento não é difícil saber que um código é Java ou C# porque é fora do padrão e nem precisa olhar o binário.

Se nada disso funcionar aí tem que procurar por outros sinais, como a forma de construir o código para tentar ver se bate com o que uma determinada linguagem faz. Bem mais complicado e fácil de errar. Obviamente que tem que conhecer como compiladores específicos geram binários.

Existem utilitários que ajudam nessa tarefa, mas nunca os usei para isso:

- [PEiD](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/PEiD) (tem outros nessa wiki)
- [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [ILDAsm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/f7dy01k1(v=vs.80)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/)
- [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/index.shtml)
- [Stud PE](http://www.cgsoftlabs.ro/studpe.html)
- [Detect It Easy](https://github.com/horsicq/Detect-It-Easy)
- [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/PE_Explorer_disassembler.htm)

Alguns prometem milagres que não são realistas. Só dá para garantir nos casos mais óbvios onde você mesmo olhando o binário pode ver o que é. Esses que eu citei são apenas ferramentas para ajudar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Se a pessoa que negativou me disser o que tem de errado na minha resposta eu posso melhorá-la.

Answer (score 8):

> Corroborando a resposta do Maniero, em ambiente Windows não existe maneira garantida de saber qual a linguagem em que o executável foi escrito.

### O que é um executável.

Um programa executável ou arquivo executável, também conhecido com imagem binária, em informática é um arquivo em que seu conteúdo deve ser interpretado como um programa por um sistema operacional.

Normalmente, eles possuem a representação binária das instruções de máquina de um processador específico, mas podem conter também uma forma intermediária(IL ou JAVA Bytecode) que podem ser necessários serviços de um interpretador(JIT) para executar.

Na maioria das arquiteturas modernas, um arquivo executável contém muitas informações que não fazem parte do programa em si, como por exemplo informações sobre o ambiente necessário para a execução do programa, informação simbólica e de depuração, ou outra informação usada pelo sistema operacional na preparação do programa a ser executado.

Os executáveis possuem chamadas aos serviços do sistema operacional além das instruções de máquina comuns. Isto significa que os executáveis normalmente são específicos a um sistema operacional além de serem específicos a um processador.

### Windows Portable Executable(PE)

O termo portable (portátil) refere-se a portabilidade sobre todos os sistemas operacionais Windows (em ambas versões de 32 e 64 bits). O formato PE é basicamente uma estrutura de dados que encapsula a informação necessária para que o carregador do sistema Windows possa manipular o código executável(linguagem de máquina). Isso inclui biblioteca dinâmica de referências para linking, exportação e importação de API, dados de administração de recursos, dados de thread-local storage (TLS).

Nos sistemas operacionais Windows NT, o PE é usado para EXE, DLL, OBJ, SYS, e outros tipos de arquivos. A especificação Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI) diz que o PE é um padrão de formato executável nos ambientes EFI. PE é uma versão modificada do formato COFF do Unix. PE/COFF é um termo alternativo.

### Por que não existe maneira garantida de saber qual a linguagem em que o executável foi escrito?

Na página da Microsoft [Windows Portable Executable](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/desktop/Debug/pe-format), onde é definido o padrão Windows de executável portável, não existe um campo dentro do arquivo executável que seja destinado a assinatura da linguagem ou do compilador que produziu o arquivo.

Na verdade só existe um campo onde essa informação possa ser passada que é o campo `attribute certificate`. Mesmo que essa informação possa ser passada ela pode não estar presente pois não é mandatória, varia de certificado para certificado.

### API para ler os certificados de um executável do Windows?

Para ler o certificados de um executável você deve incluir o cabeçalho [`imagehlp.h`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/desktop/api/imagehlp/), em seu programa escrito em C/C++, onde estão definidos a estrutura `WIN_CERTIFICATE` e as funções `ImageGetCertificateHeader` e `ImageGetCertificateData`, onde:

`WIN_CERTIFICATE` é a estrutura de dados que conterá as informações obtidas da extração do certificado. E possui a seguinte assinatura:

```
typedef struct _WIN_CERTIFICATE {
    DWORD       dwLength;
    WORD        wRevision;
    WORD        wCertificateType;   // WIN_CERT_TYPE_xxx
    BYTE        bCertificate[ANYSIZE_ARRAY];
} WIN_CERTIFICATE, *LPWIN_CERTIFICATE;
```

A função [`ImageGetCertificateHeader`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/desktop/api/imagehlp/nf-imagehlp-imagegetcertificateheader) obtém o cabeçalho de um certificado especifico. Possui a seguinte assinatura:

```
BOOL IMAGEAPI ImageGetCertificateHeader(
  HANDLE            FileHandle,
  DWORD             CertificateIndex,
  LPWIN_CERTIFICATE Certificateheader
);
```

Onde:

```
FileHandle
```

É o handle para a imagem binária. Esse handler deve ser aberto acesso do tipo `FILE_READ_DATA`.

```
CertificateIndex
```

O índice do certificado cujo o cabeçalho será retornado.

```
Certificateheader
```

Ponteiro para estrutura `WIN_CERTIFICATE` que receberá o cabeçalho do certificado.

Já a função [`ImageGetCertificateData`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/desktop/api/imagehlp/nf-imagehlp-imagegetcertificatedata) extrai a completa certificação do arquivo. Possui a seguinte assinatura:

```
BOOL IMAGEAPI ImageGetCertificateData(
  HANDLE            FileHandle,
  DWORD             CertificateIndex,
  LPWIN_CERTIFICATE Certificate,
  PDWORD            RequiredLength
);
```

Onde:

```
FileHandle
```

É o handle para a imagem binária. Esse handler deve ser aberto acesso do tipo `FILE_READ_DATA`.

```
CertificateIndex
```

O índice do certificado cujo o cabeçalho será retornado.

```
Certificate
```

Ponteiro para estrutura `WIN_CERTIFICATE` que receberá o cabeçalho do certificado.
Se o buffer não for grande o suficiente para conter a estrutura, a função falhará e o ultimo código de erro será setado para `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`.

```
RequiredLength
```

Como entrada esse parâmetro especifica o comprimento do buffer de Certificado em bytes. Em caso de sucesso esse valor retorna o comprimento do certificado.

### Observações finais.

Além dos softwares que o Maniero já citou em sua resposta eu adicionao o [ExifTool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). É fácil de usar, está disponível em Windows/Linux, faz parte do back end do VirusTotal e é capaz de obter informações de vários tipos de arquivos.
Exemplo de uso nele mesmo:
Z:\Downloads>"exiftool(-k).exe" "exiftool(-k).exe"

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.13
File Name                       : exiftool(-k).exe
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 6.4 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2016:03:12 20:31:08+01:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2016:04:02 16:37:16+02:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2016:04:02 16:37:16+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : Win32 EXE
File Type Extension             : exe
MIME Type                       : application/octet-stream
Machine Type                    : Intel 386 or later, and compatibles
Time Stamp                      : 2006:06:02 12:45:17+02:00
PE Type                         : PE32
Linker Version                  : 6.0
Code Size                       : 12288
Initialized Data Size           : 917504
Uninitialized Data Size         : 0
Entry Point                     : 0x354c
OS Version                      : 4.0
Image Version                   : 0.0
Subsystem Version               : 4.0
Subsystem                       : Windows command line
File Version Number             : 10.1.3.0
Product Version Number          : 10.1.3.0
File Flags Mask                 : 0x003f
File Flags                      : Debug
File OS                         : Windows NT 32-bit
Object File Type                : Executable application
File Subtype                    : 0
Language Code                   : Process default
Character Set                   : Unicode
Comments                        : ExifTool EXE for Windows
Company Name                    : Phil Harvey
File Description                : Read and Write meta information
File Version                    : 10.1.3.0
Internal Name                   : ExifTool
Legal Copyright                 : Copyright (c) 2003-2016, Phil Harvey
Legal Trademarks                :
Original File Name              : exiftool(-k).exe
Private Build                   :
Product Name                    : ExifTool
Product Version                 : 10.1.3.0
Special Build                   :
Build Date                      : 2016:03:12 14:27:51
Bundled Perl Version            : ActivePerl 5.8.7
Home Page                       : http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/
```

Note na penúltima linha a informação...

```
Bundled Perl Version            : ActivePerl 5.8.7
```

... que indica a linguagem em que o executável foi gerado. Porém como já foi explicado nem todos os executáveis terão essa informação, principalmente essa pois é adicionada especificamente pelo ActivePerl. Sugerindo então que cada executável deve ser analisado caso a caso, não existindo assim uma maneira sistematizada de se obter a linguagem em que o executável foi gerado.

Answer (score 3):

Pesquisei um pouco sobre o assunto, percebi que tempos atras e até os dias atuais se usa engenharia reversa para descobrir em qual linguagem o programa/aplicativo foi criado, mas dependendo da segurança e criptografia do programa fica bem difícil.

Portando hoje em dia está um pouco mais "pratico" saber isso, com alguns programas específicos, encontrei em um artigo um dos programas usados, segue abaixo:

[1]https://www.arquivoti.net/como-saber-em-que-linguagem-um-programa-foi-escrito/